# Cache Static content (js/css) in Tomcat 8 (no java app)

Tags: .htaccess, tomcat

I have a static page which loads large js/css files. How can i tell Tomcat to add expires header when serving them to browser?
I' looking for something similar to .htaccess mechanism in Tomcat.

(I use Tomcat, because in my html pages i make some request to a Java-based application- which has already been added to Tomcat. But that's totally a separate application from my webpages.)

Thanks in advance